# Does ASP.net MVC 3.0 RTM play nice with the ASYNC CTP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, async-ctp

ASP.net MVC 3.0 RC1 clashed with the ASYNC CTP in visual studio 2010.
Does anyone know if the newly released MVC 3.0 RTM will happily co-exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The changes that MVC 3 makes to VS and the changes that the Async CTP makes to VS are incompatible.

However, there is an upcoming SP1 for Visual Studio.  When that's released, the Async CTP [will be refreshed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/13ea2a78-50e3-46b6-b159-9dbbb652d88b) to work with it.  (MVC 3 RTM was already designed to be compatible with SP1 when it's released, so they'll happily coexist at that time.)

Comment: Thanks Levi - saved me the hassles of reinstalling VS2010